# npm install dependency nested node_modules folder to the upper level

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, npm

I got this error after i updated the node&npm version. 
Two shots below:
[image: in my package.json]

[image]

you can see all the nested node_modules come to the upper level
Anyone knows how to solve this? 
Thx so much.